# finding a general solution of a ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working on this problem which I don't know how to approach.

I need to find a general solution of a given ODE, and here is the equation:

$(2x\sin(y)\cos(y))y' = 4x^2 + \sin^2y$

I feel like substituting $2y$ as $v$ should be the right way to solve it, but it didn't work out very well for me - the trigonometry got super weird.

Substituting $\sin(y)$ as $v$ didn't work out very well either. So I'm kinda out of options.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(2x\sin(y)\cos(y))y' = 4x^2 + \sin^2y$$
$u= \sin^2y$

$u'=2\sin(y)\cos(y)y'$
$$xu' =4x^2 + u$$
Linear ODE  easy to solve :
$$u=4x^2+cx$$
$$y=\pm\arcsin\left(\sqrt{4x^2+cx}\right)$$

Comment: Hint: The derivative of sin^2y is 2sinycosy * dy/dx